# How to allocate local variable in LLVM using c++ api

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to declare local variable and set the value on my own using c++ API. The closest thing I found is this
`auto AI = new AllocaInst(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(context), 0, "local", entry);`
entry is a BasicBlock. However it just produces `%local = alloca i32` and not the value. How can I change its value?

Comment: Change using StoreInst, read using LoadInst.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. By the way could you tell me how to output integer? I have done it for string.

Comment: You mean print an integer?

Comment: You mean print an integer?

Comment: yeah I know how to print a string